# Get two Database Table Values to One JavaFX TreeTable

Tags: javafx, treetableview, jxtreetable

I have two classes Customer and Product.i stored this class values in database as a two table one for customer other for product. i use inner join for retrieve this data.i want to show this data in JavaFX TreeTable.there is plenty of tutorial but they only works for one class.this my code so far but it not working.im not javaFX pro.

```
Connection con;
PreparedStatement ps;
ResultSet rs;

@FXML
private JFXButton close;

@FXML
private JFXTreeTableView<Product> detailsTable;


@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> searchStatus;

@FXML
private JFXComboBox<String> searchLocation;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Customer, String> cname;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Customer, String> cnic;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Customer, String> cphone;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, String> pbrand;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, String> ptype;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, Integer> prcc;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, String> plocation;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<Product, String> pshoptype;

@FXML
private TreeTableColumn<String, Date> pdate;


@FXML
void OnClickSearch(KeyEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void searchByLocation(ActionEvent event) {

}

@FXML
void searchByStatus(ActionEvent event) {

}

private ObservableList<Customer> cData;

private ObservableList<Product> pData;




@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    con= DBConnect.connect();
    cData=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    pData= FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        rs=con.createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT c.customerName,c.customerNic,c.customerPhone,p.productBrand,p.productType,p.productRcc,p.productLocation,p.productShopType,p.productDate From customer as c INNER JOIN product as p ON c.customerId=p.customerId ");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("GET DATA TO TABLE ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        while(rs.next()){

            //pData.add(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3),rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getInt(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getDate(9));
            cData.add(new Customer(rs.getString(1),rs.getString(2),rs.getString(3)));
            pData.add(new Product (rs.getString(4),rs.getString(5),rs.getInt(6),rs.getString(7),rs.getString(8),rs.getDate(9)));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("RS.Next() Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    cname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Customer,String>("customerNam"));
    cnic.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Customer,String>("nic"));
    cphone.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Customer,String>("phone"));
    pbrand.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product,String>("brand"));
    ptype.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product,String>("type"));
    prcc.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product,Integer>("rccNo"));
    plocation.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product,String>("location"));
    pshoptype.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Product,String>("shopType"));
    pdate.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Customer,Date>("date"));


    System.out.println("For Testing");
}
```

Comment: You could create some kind of combination class to have both items (customer and product?) in one class... but there may be other ways.

Comment: yeah i did.i dont have any choice at the moment